# Ruby date format for PayPal Button Manager API

Tags: date, utc, iso8601, paypal

I can't get a date format that PayPal will accept via its PayPal Button manager API. "The start date specified is invalid." is the error.

Attempt 1: copy the string directly from the documentation:

```
"start_date": "2017-12-22T09:13:49Z"
```

I saw this https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK/issues/107 so tried

```
strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ') and utc.iso8601

start_date = "1980-02-19T00:37:04Z"
start_date = (DateTime.now - 10.years).utc.iso8601
start_date = (DateTime.now - 10.years).utc

@bm_build_button_search = @api.build_bm_button_search({ "start_date" => start_date })
# Make API call & get response
@bm_button_search_response = @api.BMButtonSearch(@bm_build_button_search)

@Errors=[#<PayPal::SDK::ButtonManager::DataTypes::ErrorType:0x007fa58b12e110 @ShortMessage="Invalid Argument", @LongMessage="The start date specified is invalid.", @ErrorCode="11998

(byebug) @bm_build_button_search.start_date.class
PayPal::SDK::Core::API::DataTypes::SimpleTypes::DateTime
So it looks like PayPal is fine with this DateTime format but when I call
@api.BMButtonSearch(@bm_build_button_search)
```

I get the error @LongMessage="The start date specified is invalid."

Answer (score 0):

I just verified following script using  **Ruby version 2.3.3** and its working fine. Following is the script i used in ruby console.

```
Step1: install Paypal SDK 
$ gem install paypal-sdk-buttonmanager 


Step2:

require 'paypal-sdk-buttonmanager'
@api = PayPal::SDK::ButtonManager::API.new(
:mode      => "sandbox",  # Set "live" for production
:app_id    => "APP-80W284485P519543T",
:username  => "jb-us-seller_api1.paypal.com",
:password  => "WX4WTU3S8MY44S7F",
:signature => "AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A7yDhhsPUU2XhtMoZXsWHFxu-
RWy" )

Step3:

 start_date = "1980-02-19T00:37:04Z"
 @bm_build_button_search = @api.build_bm_button_search({ "start_date" => start_date })
 @bm_button_search_response = @api.BMButtonSearch(@bm_build_button_search)
```

Response: I, [2017-05-06T05:43:14.803444 #6541]  INFO -- : Action: BMButtonSearch
I, [2017-05-06T05:43:14.803551 #6541]  INFO -- : Request[post]: https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/

I, [2017-05-06T05:43:27.057413 #6541]  INFO -- : Response[200]: OK, Duration: 12.254s

```
**Please verify using Ruby 2.3.3. Screenshot has been attached. thanks!**
```

reference: https://github.com/paypal/buttonmanager-sdk-ruby

[image: Respone API CALL]

Comment: I still get an error from the rails console. How is that possible that you and I are getting different results with the same @api configuration?  
Request[post]: https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/
Response[200]: OK, Duration: 0.354s
 => #<PayPal::SDK::ButtonManager::DataTypes::BMButtonSearchResponseType:0x007fc55250aec8  @Errors=[#<PayPal::SDK::ButtonManager::DataTypes::ErrorType:0x007fc5525096e0 @ShortMessage="Invalid Argument", @LongMessage="The start date specified is invalid.", @ErrorCode="11998"

Comment: This works in IRB but not in Rails - that is the problem.  The issue is with date formats in Rails.